# zsh: command not found: jupyter

Tags: pip, jupyter, zsh

I installed juypter with pip3. This is the output of `pip3 show Jupiter`:

```
Name: jupyter
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.
Home-page: http://jupyter.org
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.org
License: BSD
Location: /Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages
Requires: notebook, ipywidgets, ipykernel, qtconsole, nbconvert, jupyter-console
Required-by:
```

`which python3` and `which pip3`output:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

When I type any `Jupiter` command zsh returns: `command not found: jupyter`

I read that I have modify my §PATH variable.

I tried changing it to both

```
export PATH=/Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages
export PATH=/Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.8
```

If I search for "Jupyter" in Finder I can find for example a `jupyter-notebook` exec and run it.

How can I use the Jupyter commands from my terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both PATH definitions you wrote don't make sense, because you have removed the standard directories from the PATH. You need to find the directory, where the executable file `juypter` resides, and then **add** this directory to your PATH. This is the same process as with any other program you want to execute through your PATH.

As an alternative, you can always invoke `juypter` by specifying a path explicitly:

```
/path/to/your/installed/file/juypter
```

If you don't know into which directoy `pip` placed your file, you can try a

```
find / -name juypter 2>/dev/null
```

The error redirection is advisable, because you will otherwise get plenty of error messages about directories `find` is not allowed to cd into.